# "Implicit destructor" in c++

Tags: c++, linker, destructor

I have some header file Coordinate.h, some Coordinate.inl and some build_geometry.cpp using Coordinate type.

Coordinate.h has two versions, older one with `~Coordinate();` defined and the newer one without destructor definition line. Similarly, Coordinate.inl in newer version does not mention any destructor definition and older version contains:

```
    INLINE
    Coordinate::~Coordinate()
    {
    }
```

Now I have to compile build_geometry.cpp against Coordinate.h/Coordinate.inl which works fine only with the older version of Coordinate.h/Coordinate.inl. Otherwise it will ends with error:

```
    build_geometry.o: build_geometry.cpp:203: more undefined references to `geos::geom::Coordinate::~Coordinate()' follow
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It is apparently caused at ends of cycles/methods in which Coordinate type is used.

So the question is how to compile and link without these empty destructors declared somewhere?

Comment: Have you defined a function body for the destructor in the header that you get the error?

Comment: Which toolchain are you using and on which platform.  This may be toolchain related.

Comment: Are you saying you have two Coordinate class definitions?

Comment: You are using the new Coordinate.h itself in build_geometry.cpp, right?

Comment: @marcin_j: yes, it is libgeos-3.3.3 and libgeos-3.4.2, the only diff is as mentioned: newer versions of Coordinate.h and Coordinate.iml does not contains no-op destructor and every usage of type Coordinate in build_geometry.cpp causes linkage error (in 3.4.2). I gues there is some flag/virtual/template/inline magic but I'm not a C/C++ developer.

Comment: @sajas: it is included with some other .h file I guess, there is no explicit Coordinate.h. Can be seen here: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/build_geometry.cpp

Comment: Sounds like the old header is being used somewhere. One fix is to delete it and update whatever code relies on it.

Comment: It looks like you're including the `.h` that declares the destructor, but not the `.inl` that defines it. Make sure you're really including the headers you think you are, and that you're recompiling everything that depends on them.

Comment: @Cheers and hth: Yes, thanks. I will check it. I found somewhere that destructor declaration can be leaved out in C/C++ and everything should be working.

Comment: Did you really remove the _declaration_ of ~Coordinate? Did you rebuild all (and not build incrementally)!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: there has been some outdated stuff in `/usr/local/include/...` which precedes correct version from `/usr/include/`.